# Weird event handler behavior in Angular2?

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm going to create a draggable vertical bar with Angular2. `isDragging` should be set to true when user clicks it, then `moveHandler` should be called when mouse moves. Everything seems simple, but:

1. When the if-cond in `ngOnInit` is true, "dragging" is never printed.
2. When the if-cond in `ngOnInt` if false, "dragging" is printed after mouse is up.

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Z8o9vik87vm29AqJZwd?p=preview)

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: ` <div id="handler_vertical"  (mousedown)="startDragging()"></div> `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    isDragging = false;
    width = 0;

    startDragging() {
        console.log("start dragging");
        this.isDragging = true;
    }

    dragHanlder(event: MouseEvent) {
        if (this.isDragging) {
            console.log("dragging");
            this.width -= event.movementX;
            // console.log("movementX:"+ event.movementX);
        }
    }

    stopDragging() {
        console.log("stop dragging");
        this.isDragging = false;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        window.onmouseup = this.stopDragging;

        if(false){
            window.onmousemove = this.dragHanlder;            
        }else{
            window.onmousemove = (event) => {
                console.log("moving");
                this.dragHanlder(event);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you lose the context of your method when referencing it (i.e. the "this" keyword) at this line:

```
window.onmousemove = this.dragHanlder;
```

This way `this` will be refer to `Window`:

```
dragHanlder(event: MouseEvent) {
  if (this.isDragging) { <== this === Window
```

You could leverage [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this) to retain `this`:

```
window.onmousemove = (e) => this.dragHanlder(e);

window.onmouseup = (e) => this.stopDragging(e);
```

Here is updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/2LN5EAx9RCdpI3b0Bpt5?p=preview

Comment: Thanks.  But "dragging" is still printed after mouse is up. Do you have any idea?